# How to create an lookup Map in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

While I know there's a few ways to do this, I'm most interested in finding the most idiomatic and functional Scala method.

Given the following trite example:

```
case class User(id: String)
val users = List(User("1"), User("2"), User("3"), User("4"))
```

What's the best way to create an immutable lookup Map of user.id -> User so that I can perform quick lookups by user.id.

In Java I'd probably use Google-Collection's [Maps.uniqueIndex](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) although its unique property I care less about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep the users in a List and use list.find:

```
users.find{_.id == "3"} //returns Option[User], either Some(User("3")) or None if no such user
```

or if you want to use a Map, map the list of users to a list of 2-tuples, then use the toMap method:

```
val umap = users.map{u => (u.id, u)}.toMap
```

which will return an immutable Map[String, User], then you can use

```
umap contains "1" //return true
```

or

```
umap.get("1") //returns Some(User("1"))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure all IDs are unique, the canonical way is

```
users.map(u => (u.id, u)).toMap
```

as @Dan Simon said.  However, if you are not sure all IDs are unique, then the canonical way is:

```
users.groupBy(_.id)
```

This will generate a mapping from user IDs to a *list* of users that share that ID.

Thus, there is an alternate not-entirely-canonical way to generate the map from ID to single users:

```
users.groupBy(_.id).mapValues(_.head)
```

For expert users who want to avoid the intermediate step of creating a map of lists, or a list which then gets turned into a map, there is the handy `scala.collecion.breakOut` method that builds the type that you want if there's a straightforward way to do it.  It needs to know the type, though, so this will do the trick:

```
users.map(u => (u.id,u))(collection.breakOut): Map[String,User]
```

(You can also assign to a var or val of specified type.)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the List into a Map and use it as a function:

```
  case class User(id: String)
  val users = List(User("1"), User("2"), User("3"))

  val usersMap = users map { case user @ User(id) => id -> user } .toMap

  usersMap("1")    // Some(User("1"))
  usersMap("0")    // None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a numeric index:

```
scala> users.map (u=> u.id.toInt -> u).toMap 
res18: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,User] =
  Map((1,User(1)), (2,User(2)), (3,User(3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maps are functions too, their apply method provides access to the value associated with a particular key (or a NoSuchElementException is thrown for an unknown key) so this makes for a very clean lookup syntax. Following on from Dan Simon's answer and using a more semantically meaningful name:

```
scala> val Users = users map {u  => (u.id, u)} toMap      
Users: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,User] = Map((1,User(1)), (2,User(2)), (3,User(3)))
```

which then provides the following lookup syntax:

```
scala> val user2 = Users("2")
user2: User = User(2)
```